# Pass PHP Array to JSON and JS: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, php, gridstack

i always get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" when i try to echo a PHP Variable to a JS Variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var options = {
           float: false,
           removable: '.trash',
           removeTimeout: 100,
           acceptWidgets: '.grid-stack-item',
           resizable: { handles: 'e, se, s, sw, w' }
           };
        $('#grid').gridstack(options);

        var data = "<?php echo json_encode($serializedData); ?>";
```

My PHP:

```
$serializedData = array();
$str = "SELECT gri_id as 'id', gri_plugin as 'plugin', gri_gridContent as 'content', gri_gridPosX as 'x', gri_gridPosY as 'y', gri_gridSizeX as 'width', gri_gridSizeY as 'height' FROM tGrid WHERE gri_location = '$loc'";
$stmt = $db->prepare($str);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($result as $value) {
  $function = $value["plugin"];
  $data = $function($value['id'], $db);
  $value['content'] = $data;
  array_push($serializedData, $value);
}
```

Comment: Remove the quotation marks: `var data = <?php echo json_encode($serializedData); ?>;` If you look at the generated code, it should be pretty clear what the error is.

Comment: Damn i didnt saw that. Thanks.

Comment: @FelixKling : Please post your comment as answer, so that it can be marked accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming JSON is a valid snippet of javascript, why should we wrap it into quotes? You expect data will become Object, but it becomes String for now.

Do:

```
var data = <?php echo json_encode($serializedData) ?>;
```